# Can Lorentz force density be zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Consider a compactly supported current density $\bf J$ in free space which gives rise to a magnetic field $\bf B$. Can this system's Lorentz force density, $\frac{1}{c} {\bf J} \times {\bf B}$, be zero nontrivially? If so, do you have any examples? Assume that the current density
is steady (ie $\nabla \cdot {\bf J}=0$).

The following bit of math is as far as I have gotten in my attempt to answer this question. For a steady current density (ie $\nabla \cdot {\bf J}=0$) Ampere's Law, $\nabla \times {\bf B} = \frac{4\pi}{c} {\bf J}$, applies so that the force density $\bf F$ can be written as:

$${\bf F} = \frac{1}{4\pi} (\nabla \times {\bf B}) \times {\bf B}$$

which, using a vector calculus identity, can be written as

$${\bf F} = \frac{1}{8\pi} \nabla ({\bf B} \cdot {\bf B}) - \frac{1}{4\pi} ({\bf B} \cdot \nabla) {\bf B}.$$

I don't see a reason why this force could not be zero. Can it? Am I missing something?

Note that, of course, the constraint $\nabla \cdot {\bf B}=0$ applies as well.